# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 4711: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, unicode, decoder, cp1251, disnake

Soo

````
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands
import time

from disnake import Intents
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="*", intents=disnake.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user.name} has connected to Discord!')
    channel1 = bot.get_channel(1105450189688414208)  
    channel2 = bot.get_channel(1105452174546321498)  
    last_line_file1 = ''
    last_line_file2 = ''
    while True:
        # with open("C:\\Users\\______\\____\\_____\\______\\_____\\_____\\server_log.txt", 'r', encoding='cp1251') as file1:
        #     last_line = file1.readlines()[-1].strip() символы переноса строки
        #     if last_line != last_line_file1:
        #         await channel1.send(f'```\n{last_line}\n```')
        #         last_line_file1 = last_line  
        with open('"C:\\Users\\______\\____\\_____\\______\\_____\\_____\\server_chat_log.txt"', 'r', encoding='cp1251') as file2:
            last_line = file2.readlines()[-1].strip()  
            if last_line != last_line_file2:
                await channel2.send(last_line)
                last_line_file2 = last_line 
        time.sleep(0.5)
bot.run('---')
````

error:  ***line 22, in on_ready
last_line = file2.readlines()[-1].strip()  # Получаем последнюю строку из файла и удаляем символы переноса строки
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 4711: character maps to undefined***

server_chat_log.txt encoded in cp1251.

With the encoding qualifier I realized that the file is written in cp1251, but the code stops working (server_chat_log.txt there is a Cyrillic encoded)

Example  of server_chat_log.txt:

```
[00:15:59]: [Say] (KU_LnRtDiLl) groznyjsasison: Сѓ РјРµРЅСЏ РЅРѕСЂРј Р»СѓС‚ С‚РµРїРµСЂСЊ
[00:16:56]: [Say] (KU_l2ws0ArT) РљРѕРЅРЅРѕСЂ RK800 (????): СЃРєРѕРє Сѓ С‚РµР±СЏ РєР°РјРЅСЏ?
[00:17:05]: [Say] (KU_LnRtDiLl) groznyjsasison: РєР°РјРЅСЏ 14
[00:17:06]: [Join Announcement] Aleksey Meatballs in DST
[00:17:09]: [Say] (KU_LnRtDiLl) groznyjsasison: РєСЂРµРјРЅСЏ 24
[00:17:13]: [Say] (KU_l2ws0ArT) РљРѕРЅРЅРѕСЂ RK800 (????): РґРѕР±СѓРґСЊ 40 С…РѕС‚СЏ Р±С‹
[00:17:17]: [Say] (KU_LnRtDiLl) groznyjsasison: Р·РЅР°СЋ
[00:17:18]: [Say] (KU_l2ws0ArT) РљРѕРЅРЅРѕСЂ RK800 (????): РєСЂРµРјРЅСЏ РёС‚Р°Рє Сѓ РјРµРЅСЏ 40
[00:19:42]: [Say] (KU_LnRtDiLl) groznyjsasison: РґР°РІР°Р№ СЏ СѓРіР»СЏ РґРѕР±СѓРґСѓ
[00:19:46]: [Say] (KU_LnRtDiLl) groznyjsasison: РґР»СЏ РєР°Р·Р°РЅР°
[00:19:49]: [Say] (KU_l2ws0ArT) РљРѕРЅРЅРѕСЂ RK800 (????): РіРѕ
[00:19:59]: [Say] (KU_l2ws0ArT) РљРѕРЅРЅРѕСЂ RK800 (????): СЏ Р·РѕР»РѕС‚Рѕ РґРѕР±С‹Р»
[00:20:09]: [Say] (KU_LnRtDiLl) groznyjsasison: Сѓ РјРµРЅСЏ 2 Р·РѕР»РѕС‚Р°
[00:20:24]: [Say] (KU_l2ws0ArT) РљРѕРЅРЅРѕСЂ RK800 (????): РґРѕР±Р°РІСЊ РјРµРЅСЏ РІ РґСЂ
[00:20:31]: [Say] (KU_l2ws0ArT) РљРѕРЅРЅРѕСЂ RK800 (????): РЅР°С… РµС‚Рѕ РіРѕРІРѕСЂРёС‚СЊ РІ РѕР±С‰РёР№ С‡Р°С‚
[00:20:38]: [Say] (KU_LnRtDiLl) groznyjsasison: РєР°Рє
[00:20:40]: [Say] (KU_LnRtDiLl) groznyjsasison: РІ РґСЂ
[00:20:41]: [Say] (KU_l2ws0ArT) РљРѕРЅРЅРѕСЂ RK800 (????): РІ СЃС‚РёРјРµ
[00:20:47]: [Say] (KU_LnRtDiLl) groznyjsasison: СЏ РЅРµ РјРѕРіСѓ
[00:20:52]: [Say] (KU_LnRtDiLl) groznyjsasison: РЅРµ РґРѕРЅРёР»
[00:20:52]: [Say] (KU_l2ws0ArT) РљРѕРЅРЅРѕСЂ RK800 (????): СЏ С‚РµР±Рµ Р·Р°СЏРІРєСѓ РєРёРЅСѓ
```

Comment: Judging from how `server_chat_log.txt` looks, the file was saved as UTF-8, but you tried to load it as CP1251. Saving `у меня норм лут теперь` in UTF-8 but loading it as CP1251 will result in `Сѓ РјРµРЅСЏ РЅРѕСЂРј Р»СѓС‚ С‚РµРїРµСЂСЊ`

Comment: @qrsngky
From CP1251:     

[00:20:40]: [Say] (KU_LnRtDiLl) groznyjsasison: РІ РґСЂ
[00:20:41]: [Say] (KU_l2ws0ArT) РљРѕРЅРЅРѕСЂ RK800 (????): РІ СЃС‚РёРјРµ

To  UTF-8     

[00:20:40]: [Say] (KU_LnRtDiLl) groznyjsasison: в др
[00:20:41]: [Say] (KU_l2ws0ArT) Коннор RK800 (????): в стиме

Comment: If you use `encoding='utf-8'`, do you get a different error?